# if/else not receiving value at array in C

Tags: c, if-statement

My task was to create a program that would print out the total number of newlines, spaces and tabs of a user input. I've looked around at other questions but none of them match my exact problem.

I decided to use the 'if/else if' function to get a better grasp of the subject, still, something got in the way as the results printed are all 0.

What am I missing here? Also, and this it out of focus, I am using VSCode for my studies, but when I try to run the code there's 'nothing' happening in the output section, so now i've changed it to display at the terminal section. What is the problem happening here, and how should I approach it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int c;
    int count[] = {0,0,0};  // 0 = newlines, 1 = spaces, 2 = tabs
    
    while ( (c = getchar() != EOF)) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            count[0]++;
        }
        else if (c == ' '){
            count[1]++;
        }
        else if (c == '\t') {
            count[2]++;
        }
    }
    printf("Newlines: %d\nSpaces: %d\nTabs: %d", count[0],count[1],count[2]);
}
```

Comment: `while ( (c = getchar() != EOF))` should be `while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)`. You're setting `c` to the result of `!=` instead of the result of `getchar()`

Comment: The comparison operator `!=` have higher [*precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than assignment `=`.